# formatting date to dd-mm-yyyy in jsp

Tags: jsp, date-format

I need date format in `dd-mm-yyyy` format in `jsp.My database`(dd/mm/yyyy-having date datatype in db) is read to jsp(using form bean, CmFrm.getExpireDate() - having datatype as string).
It is now read as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.a` in jsp i want it to read in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.
I have tried using --

```
String txtdate =CmFrm.getExpireDate(); 
SimpleDateFormat pd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date date = (Date) pd.parse(txtdate); 
String DisplayDate= df.format(date); 
System.out.println("MyExpireDate.."+DisplayDate);
```

I get `unparsable` error.

I have applied format function alone as -

```
String txtdate =CmFrm.getExpireDate(); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
System.out.println("Date.."+df.format(txtdate));
```

here jsp goes `blank`.
please help as how to display date on jsp in `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: your first code will work just check out some other errors and calm down ..

Comment: i get unparseable date: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" while using first code.

Answer (score 2):

Should do you good...

```
String MyDate = CmFrm.getExpireDate();
SimpleDateFormat parseDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatDdate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date) parseDate.parse(MyDate);
String DisplayDate= formatDate.format(date);
```

Output example: 2016-11-19

Answer (score 1):

I tried your first code and I don't get any exceptions:

```
String txtdate = "06/06/2012"; 
SimpleDateFormat pd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

Date date = null;
try {
    date = (Date) pd.parse(txtdate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

String DisplayDate= df.format(date); 
System.out.println("MyExpireDate.."+DisplayDate);
```

When I execute the following, I get:

```
MyExpireDate..2012-06-06
```

Maybe you've imported the wrong date libraries? I imported these:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Comment: It would help alot if you "green check" my answer as the right one :)

Comment: Steve, I up-voted it :-) But I suggest OP to "green check" your answer as the most apt one cause you used OP's code...

Comment: you did pretty much the same thing but your solution in shorter. save space ftw

Comment: i have already imported all those files and all this code is placed in jsp file,its not working,i get blank screen when i put format to my date.

Comment: maybe you're getting a NULL value on your jsp page. How does your jsp page looks like?

Comment: when i put now Date() in format i get correct format ,when i pass database date to this jsp is blank. And what is jsp look like means??

Comment: then you're definitely getting null value on your jsp page. print out the "txtdate" before you're formatting it to see if you're getting the date-string at all

Comment: i have used following code import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateEx {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  //String valueFromDB = "2012/06/06 00:00:00";
  String valueFromDB = "2012-12-31 00:00:00";
  Date d = new Date(valueFromDB);
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  String dateWithoutTime = sdf.format(d);

  System.out.println("sdf.format(d) " + dateWithoutTime);

 }

}
i get IllegalArgumentException()when i use date as "2012-12-31 00:00:00"

Comment: I am using Oracle database where date is stored as dd/mm/yyyy, I am getting an error on a date field (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)when i put hardcode value "2012-12-31 00:00:00.0"i guess this because of timestamp format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff which is creating problem.

Comment: mixing datetime and timestamp causes alot of problems. my advice is to change timestamp to datetime in your database