# how to make date looking at jsp only yyyy-mm-dd format - truncate time

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

I have to do display time with opportunity to edit it.

I used Mysql DB and this columns has **date** type.

But some trouble is that it is displayed `DATE TIME`:

> 2014-04-02 00:00:00.0

It looks at browser:

[image: time view]

I want to truncate time.

Here is snippet from **jsp**:

```
<head>
    <title>Project info</title>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#startDate").datepicker();
            $("#endDate").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
// ...
<td>${task.startDate}</td>
<td>${task.endDate}</td>
```

And snippet with edit options:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <span><fmt:message key="task.start"/></span>
       <input class="form-control" placeholder="<fmt:message key="task.start"/>"
                                                       name="start_date-${task.taskId}" id="startDate" type="date"
                                                       value="${task.startDate}"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <span><fmt:message key="task.end"/></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="<fmt:message key="task.end"/>"
                                                       name="end_date-${task.taskId}" id="endDate" type="date"
                                                       value="${task.endDate}"/>
 </div>
```

I easy extract it as property.

At servlet side it is parsed:

```
        Task task = taskService.getByID(id);

        String name = (!ValidationUtils.isNullOrEmpty(request.getParameter("name-" + id)))
                ? request.getParameter("task_name-" + id) : task.getTitle();
        String description = (!ValidationUtils.isNullOrEmpty(request.getParameter("task_description-" + id)))
                ? request.getParameter("task_description-" + id) : task.getDescription();
        String state = request.getParameter("state-" + id);
        int estimateTime = (request.getParameter("estimate_time-" + id) != null)
                ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("estimate_time-" + id))
                : task.getEstimateTime();
        Date startDate = (request.getParameter("start_date-" + id) != null)
                ? new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(request.getParameter("start_date-" + id))
                : task.getStartDate();
        Date endDate = (request.getParameter("end_date-" + id) != null)
                ? new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(request.getParameter("end_date-" + id))
                : task.getStartDate()
```

private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd";

***How to correct view of date and make next input pattern `yyyy-mm-dd`?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

```
$(function () {
    $("#startDate, #endDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: how to convert it to date format when it is extracted from DB => `<td>${task.startDate}</td>`?

Comment: @nazar_art Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736637 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507

Answer (score 1):

Specify format as `yy-mm-dd`

```
("#startDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the parameters of `datepicker`:

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
```